# setMap() of google maps api not working

Tags: javascript, google-maps, knockout.js

I am building a map using the Google Maps API, and when I load it I get this error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'setMap' of undefined

I think toggle() from vm() is causing error but I don't know how to correct it.
My aim is to simultaneously display markers based on search.

Here is the code:

```js
var locations = [
        {"name": "Marari Beach Alappuzha" ,'location': {'lat': 9.618406, 'lng': 76.340161} },
        {"name": "Tea Mueseum" ,'location': {'lat': 10.049198, 'lng': 77.051025 }},
        {"name": "Eravikulam National Park" ,'location': {'lat': 10.116233, 'lng': 77.067791} },
        {"name": "Chimmini Wildlife Sanctuary" ,'location': {'lat': 10.428646, 'lng': 76.491031} },
        {"name": "Bekal Fort ",'location': {'lat': 12.440895, 'lng': 75.030311 }}
      ]

var markers = [];
var map;
var boolean = [];
for(i=0;i<locations.length;i++){
    boolean[i] = true;
}
function initMap() {
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        zoom: 7,
        center: {
            lat: 10.850516,
            lng: 76.271080
        }
    });
    var labels = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
    for (var i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
        var position = locations[i].location;
        var name = locations[i].name;
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            // map:map,
            position: position,
            animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
            id: i
        });
        markers.push(marker);
        marker.addListener('click', (function(marker, i) {
            return function() {
                if (marker.getAnimation() != null) {
                    marker.setAnimation(null);
                } else {
                    marker.setAnimation(google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE);
                    stopAnimation(marker);
                }
            }
        })(marker, i));

        function stopAnimation(marker) {
            setTimeout(function() {
                marker.setAnimation(null);
            }, 3000);
        };
    }
    toggle();
}

function toggle(){
    for(g=0;g<locations.length;g++){
        if(boolean[g] === true){
            markers[g].setMap(map);
        }else if(boolean[g] === false){
            markers[g].setMap(null);
        }
    }
}

var z,g;
var vm = function(){
    var self = this;
    self.loc = ko.observableArray(locations);
    self.query = ko.observable('');
    self.filteredloc = ko.computed(function () {
        z=0;
    var filter = self.query().toLowerCase();
    console.log(boolean);
    toggle();
    if (!filter) {
        return self.loc();
    } else {
        return ko.utils.arrayFilter(self.loc(), function (item) {
            boolean[z] = item.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(filter) !== -1;
            // console.log(boolean[z]+'in pos'+z);
             z++;
            return item.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(filter) !== -1;
        });
    }
});

};

ko.applyBindings(new vm());
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compaitable" content="IE-edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Neighbourhood Map</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="http://ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/jquery/jquery-1.4.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
    <script defer src="mapping.js"></script>
    <script asyc defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyAZJYwSB-hwX7EXVNXtWo7HSjyPaJNmrWc&callback=initMap"></script>

</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div id="content" class="col-3">
                <div id="content_search">
                    <form action="#">
                        <input placeholder="Search…" type="search" name="q" data-bind="value: query, valueUpdate: 'keyup'" autocomplete="off">
                    </form>
                </div>
                <div class="content_data">
                    <ul id="content_data--style" data-bind="template: {name:'location', foreach:filteredloc}"></ul>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-9">
                <h3 >Neighbourhood Map</h3>
                <div id="map"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script type="text/html" id="location">
        <li>
            <strong data-bind="text: name"></strong>
        </li>
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: (1) You never call `show()` or `hide()`. (2) The indentation in those functions is really messed up. (3) Each of those functions inadvertently creates a global variable `g`. You are missing a `var` in each one. (4) You should add `"use strict";` at the top of your source file to prevent errors like the global `g`. (5) Where are `locations` and `boolean` defined? (6) `boolean` should be changed to a more meaningful name. (7) Can you please create a complete, self-contained code snippet in your question that contains all the HTML and JavaScript code need to run and demonstrate the problem?

Comment: Sorry @ Michael Geary . I have refactored the code. Hope now you can help me

Comment: Thanks, that's a great help to be able to see all the code. I took care of step 7 for you: turning your code into an executable snippet. As you can see, there is now a *Run Code Snippet* button under your code that actually loads and runs it right here. So now people will be able to try it out and get some ideas for you.

Comment: Take a look at how I set up the snippet - it's basically just putting some special HTML comments around the JavaScript and HTML code. And don't worry, you don't have to memorize the exact syntax. There's a button above the edit box that looks like a little document with <> inside it. Click that to insert a snippet in any question, and then you can paste in the HTML/JS/CSS code.

Comment: Thank you sir  @Michael Geary. I am still banging my head for some solution .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have a solution for you, but I want to show you some ways you can greatly simplify your JavaScript code.

First, I got rid of the separate `markers` and `boolean` arrays. Instead, it's better to make those properties of the `locations` array elements. After all, `locations` is where you have your information about a location, so put *all* the information there. In the new code, each `locations` array element has a `marker` property (if a marker has been created) and a `show` property that corresponds to the former `boolean` array elements. Things get much simpler if you don't have to update separate arrays but just keep all your information in one place.

I replaced a couple of `for` loops with `forEach()`. `forEach()` takes a callback function, which is very nice because in this case it gives you a closure on the `location` argument passed to the callback. So you don't need the complicated code in `marker.addListener()` to create a closure - the closure already exists for you.

And I simplified the `toggle()` function a bit by removing and combining duplicate code.

That's all I have time for right now, but I hope it will give you some things to look at that will help you simplify your code - because simpler code is easier code to understand and debug.

```js
var locations = [
    { "name": "Marari Beach Alappuzha" ,'location': { 'lat': 9.618406, 'lng': 76.340161 } },
    { "name": "Tea Mueseum" ,'location': { 'lat': 10.049198, 'lng': 77.051025 } },
    { "name": "Eravikulam National Park" ,'location': { 'lat': 10.116233, 'lng': 77.067791 } },
    { "name": "Chimmini Wildlife Sanctuary" ,'location': { 'lat': 10.428646, 'lng': 76.491031 } },
    { "name": "Bekal Fort ",'location': { 'lat': 12.440895, 'lng': 75.030311 } }
];

var map;

function initMap() {
    map = new google.maps.Map( document.getElementById('map'), {
        zoom: 7,
        center: {
            lat: 10.850516,
            lng: 76.271080
        }
    });
    var labels = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
    locations.forEach( function( location ) {
        var marker = location.marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: location.location,
            animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP
        });
        marker.addListener( 'click', function() {
            if( marker.getAnimation() ) {
                marker.setAnimation( null );
            } else {
                marker.setAnimation( google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE );
                stopAnimation( marker );
            }
        });

        function stopAnimation(marker) {
            setTimeout( function() {
                marker.setAnimation(null);
            }, 3000 );
        }
    });
    toggle();
}

function toggle() {
    locations.forEach( function( location ) {
        if( location.marker ) {
            location.marker.setMap( location.show ? map : null );
        }
    });
}

var vm = function() {
    var self = this;
    self.loc = ko.observableArray( locations );
    self.query = ko.observable('');
    self.filteredloc = ko.computed( function () {
        var z = 0;
        var filter = self.query().toLowerCase();
        toggle();
        if( ! filter ) {
            return self.loc();
        } else {
            return ko.utils.arrayFilter( self.loc(), function( item ) {
                boolean[z] = item.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(filter) !== -1;
                // console.log(boolean[z]+'in pos'+z);
                z++;
                return item.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(filter) !== -1;
            });
        }
    });
}

ko.applyBindings( new vm() );
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compaitable" content="IE-edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Neighbourhood Map</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="http://ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/jquery/jquery-1.4.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
    <script defer src="mapping.js"></script>
    <script asyc defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyAZJYwSB-hwX7EXVNXtWo7HSjyPaJNmrWc&callback=initMap"></script>

</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div id="content" class="col-3">
                <div id="content_search">
                    <form action="#">
                        <input placeholder="Search…" type="search" name="q" data-bind="value: query, valueUpdate: 'keyup'" autocomplete="off">
                    </form>
                </div>
                <div class="content_data">
                    <ul id="content_data--style" data-bind="template: {name:'location', foreach:filteredloc}"></ul>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-9">
                <h3 >Neighbourhood Map</h3>
                <div id="map"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script type="text/html" id="location">
        <li>
            <strong data-bind="text: name"></strong>
        </li>
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you sir . Thanks for the help . Much appreciated .